# Wordpress link to show popup box

Tags: links

I have a button on my wordpress page that is wrapped in  tags. Can I edit the link so that when someone clicks on it, it just shows them a popup message box, and stays on the page that they were on?

Thanks!

Sample code:

```
<a title="My Title" href="www.website.com/we-should-change-this-url"><img class="alignleft  wp-image-652" alt="ITIN2" src="www.website.com/image-url" width="220" height="55" /></a>
```

Comment: Please add relevant code! Right now the answer would just be: "Yes, you can do that".

Comment: See update above

Comment: Can you try again.

Comment: Sorry - I think it didn't show up because it wasn't in code tags. Try again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more to it do you think but here's a simple popup message [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/mmetsalu/hBX6E/2/) I've created.

Have a look at it and let me know if you need further help.

**For future reference:** This sort of question should be asked at Stack Overflow!